# Accessing array which is returned by a VBA Macro function

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how can I access to the value of an array returned by a function.
as far as i know, the returned value should have the same function name.

```
Function PathFinder(sheet1 As String, word1 As String) As Integer()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim temp(1, 2)

Set rng = Sheets(sheet1).Range("A:D")
Set rngFound = rng.Find(word1, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "not found"
Else:
     temp(1, 1) = rngFound.Row
     temp(1, 2) = rngFound.Column

     PathFinder = temp
End If

End Function
```

This have been done, I didn't find how to access to the value "PathFinder(1,1)" and "PathFinder(1,2)"

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns array, so:

```
Dim arr() as Integer
arr = PathFinder("sheet","word")

Debug.Print arr(1,1)
Debug.Print arr(1,2)
```

I suggest to remove 2-dimensional array (temp):

```
Function PathFinder(sheet1 As String, word1 As String) As Integer()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim temp(2) As Integer

Set rng = Sheets(sheet1).Range("A:D")
Set rngFound = rng.Find(word1, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "not found"
Else:
     temp(1) = rngFound.Row
     temp(2) = rngFound.Column
End If

PathFinder = temp

End Function

Public Sub Test()
    Dim arr() As Integer
    arr = PathFinder("sheet1", "1word")

    If arr(1) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "not found"
    Else
        Debug.Print arr(1)
        Debug.Print arr(2)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) it doesn't work - it gives you _compile error_ on line `PathFinder = temp`, because `Dim temp(2)` is variant array and `PathFinder` returns `Integer` array 2) if nothing found, `Debug.Print arr(1)` gives you _runtime error_

Answer (score 0):

I would do this one:

```
Function PathFinder(sheet1 As String, word1 As String) As Long()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim temp(1, 2) As Long

    Set rng = Sheets(sheet1).Range("A:D")
    Set rngFound = rng.Find(word1, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "not found"
    Else
        temp(1, 1) = rngFound.Row
        temp(1, 2) = rngFound.Column
    End If
    PathFinder = temp
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim res() As Long

    res = PathFinder("Sheet1", "A")
    MsgBox "Row:" & res(1, 1) & " Column: " & res(1, 2)
End Sub
```

Also note that I've slightly changed your `PathFinder` function.

- I've moved `PathFinder = temp` to the end of it. The reason is simple: if nothing found in your version line `MsgBox "Row:" & res(1, 1) & " Column: " & res(1, 2)` triggers an error, but in my version you get "magic numbers" if nothing found, i.e. it returns `0` for row and column.
- I've changed return type from `Integer()` to `Long()` because max value of `Integer` is only `32768` and sometimes you can get overflow error (since `rngFound.Row` may be greater than `32768`).